# h:outputText value not getting displayed inside h:outputLink tag

Tags: jsf, facelets

I have h:outputText inside h:outputlink tag, but text of h:outputText is not getting displayed on the front end.

```html
<h:outputLink id="test1" value="/aafdemo/pages/contact/createContact.seam"
    style="margin-left:5px"> 
    <h:outputText value="Contact" />
</h:outputLink>
```

I can see it inside the firebug, which is rendered something like this.

```
<a style="margin-left:5px"
    href="/aafdemo/pages/opportunity/createOpportunity.seam">Opportunity</a>
```

But I don't see it on the webpage. This is the part of left hand side menu which is getting displayed on all the pages, and it is not displaying "Opportunity" word on any of the page.

Strange part is value of the h:outputText tag, if I change it to something else it will display "Opportunity" tag. It is  very strange.

Comment: A live example or an SSCCE would be helpful. The problem is not visible in the code posted so far and most likely not Java/JSF/JavaEE related at all. Most likely there's just some CSS wrong.

Comment: If it was a problem of CSS, then when i change the value of h:Outputlink, it would not show that either.

Comment: Uh, okay, good luck fixing the problem.

Comment: when you change if it is getting displayed that means its working isn't it

Comment: Update on this...I can see the text on IE but not on Firefox or Chrome..

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is something with the style. I have no problem with the same code structure:

```
<h:outputText value="Please read the " />
<h:outputLink value="/termsAndConditions">
    <h:outputText value="Terms and Conditions." />
</h:outputLink>
```

And the html result is:

```
Please read the <a href="/termsAndConditions">Terms and Conditions.</a>
```